# Formatting arguments for Subprocess

Tags: python, selenium, subprocess, adb

I am capturing a screenshot with

```
time_run = current_time + "_" + c
backup_photos = "/sdcard/"+time_run+"_backup_error_photos.png"    
subprocess.check_output(["adb", "shell", "/system/bin/screencap -p " + backup_photos])
```

and I need to then pull that screenshot off of the device and store it on my computer. I have tried doing this a number of ways but am having trouble with the formatting of the subprocess arguments. Examples of what i've tried:

```
subprocess.check_output("adb", "pull", backup_photos, scripts_folder))

subprocess.call(shlex.split("adb pull " + backup_photos + ' ' + scripts_folder))
```

and various others, to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a working bash command?

Comment: adb pull /sdcard/test.png C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop works fine. But I think the issues lies in me using variables in the arguments. So if my screenshot was always named 'Test,' i'd be fine.

Comment: does check_output and call use the same arguments?

Comment: Yes, they do. Your first use of check_output is the correct way to use them

Comment: still not working...hmm

Comment: If you run `subprocess.call(["adb", "pull", backup_photos, scripts_folder])`, are there any error messages, or does it just not do anything? Also relevant, does it return 0 or some other number?

Comment: That worked! Thank you sir! Post an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first use of `subprocess.check_output()` is also the correct way to use `subprocess.call()`:

```
subprocess.call(["adb", "pull", backup_photos, scripts_folder])
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)